# Implementação de um Analisador Léxico

Tags: python, compiladores

Olá, galera! Estou fazendo a implementação de um analisador léxico de uma gramática que eu criei (utilizando o Gals). A validação da gramática foi feita utilizando o conceito de autômatos finitos, conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento eu tenho os seguintes códigos:

Arquivo lexico.py:

```
with open("transicao.txt", "r") as programa:
    arquivo = programa.readlines()
    lista = []
    for linha in arquivo:
        line = linha.strip('\n').replace(' ', '')
        for i in line:
            lista.append(i)

    with open("tokens/transicao.txt", "r") as arquivo:
        linhas = arquivo.readlines()

    def concatenar(list):
        return ''.join(list)

    def ftransicao(s, l):
        for v in linhas:  # Navega pelas linhas do arquivo de transição
            linha = v.split(',')  # Divide a string em 3 partes (estado atual, letra, próximo estado)
            if linha[0] == s:  # Se o primeiro valor da string dividida for igual o estado atual
                for z in linha[1]:  # É navegado apenas pelos valores das letras da função transição
                    if z == l:  # Se a letra lida no arquivo for igual a letra lida da palavra então é retornado o próximo estado
                        # print('{} contém {} então vai para {}'.format(s, l, linha[2]))
                        return linha[2].strip()
        return None


    atual = 'q0'
    efinal = ['q3', 'q7', 'q28', 'q9', 'q15', 'q18', 'q25', 'q33', 'q34', 'q35',
              'q36', 'q37', 'q39', 'q41', 'q42', 'q43', 'q44', 'q45', 'q46', 'q47', 'q51', 'q53']
    lexema = []

    for i in range(len(lista)):

        atual = ftransicao(atual, lista[i].strip())
        lexema += lista[i]

        if atual in efinal:
            print('Caractere identificado [ {} ]'.format(concatenar(lexema)))
            atual = 'q0'
            lexema.clear()
            continue
        elif atual is None:
            atual = 'q0'
            print('Caractere não identificado [ {} ]'.format(lista[i]))
            lexema.clear()
            continue
```

Arquivo transicao.txt que contém um exemplo da gramática:

```
run
integer f = 22;
integer g = 3;
integer n;
display();
input(n);
while(g <= numero){
f = f * i;
g = g + 1;
}
display(f);
exit
```

E a função transição descrita conforme a imagem:

```
q0,r,q1
q1,u,q2
q2,n,q3

q0,e,q4
q4,x,q5
q5,i,q6
q6,t,q7

q4,l,q26
q26,s,q27
q27,e,q28

q0,i,q8
q8,f,q9
q8,n,q10
q10,t,q11
q11,e,q12
q12,g,q13
q13,e,q14
q14,r,q15

q10,p,q16
q16,u,q17
q17,t,q18

q0,d,q19
q19,i,q20
q20,s,q21
q21,p,q22
q22,l,q23
q23,a,q24
q24,y,q25

q0,w,q29
q29,h,q30
q30,i,q31
q31,l,q32
q32,e,q33

q0,-,q34
q0,+,q35
q0,*,q36
q0,/,q37

q0,<,q38
q38,=,q39

q0,>,q40
q40,=,q41

q0,=,q42
q42,=,q43

q0,(,q44
q0,),q45
q0,{,q46
q0,},q47
q0,;,q53
```

O problema é o seguinte. De que forma eu posso fazer a validação da String, dos dígitos, identificadores conforme a imagem mostrada? Os outros estão funcionando perfeitamente e está sendo reconhecido na listagem.

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar. Boa noite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua linguagem é complexa demais para ser definida numa gramática regular. Você deve usar uma [gramática livre de contexto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica_livre_de_contexto), dessa forma você poderá inclusive definir a procedência dos operadores matemáticos e verificar parênteses balanceados.

Depois que criar a sua GLC, crie um [parser LL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analisador_sint%C3%A1tico_LL) para validar a sintaxe e gerar a [AST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_de_an%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica).